# PHP - ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Tags: php, sql, oracle, ora-01747

I'm trying to update a table called RAC_PV at my oracle database but the query is returning that error when i run my application. I thing everyting is right because i run the same query on sqldeveloper (but with manual values) and when i change the variable $preco_medio to a number like 1, it works on the application. Here's my code:

```
$preco_medio = number_format(($v_interna_real / $encargo + $vipe_real) / $v_interna_t + $vipe_t , 2, ",", ".") ;

sc_exec_sql("update RAC_PV set PRECO_MEDIO = $preco_medio where rac_anopv = {ano} and rac_mespv = {mes} and codempresa = $id_empresa and codpainel = 6 and cod_prod1 = '$id_produto'");
```

My table name  and the column names are right and checked, my variables like {ano}, {mes}, $id_produto and $preco_medio are all corretly seted. This sc_exec_sql("query here") works fine. Maybe the problem is in the $preco_medio ? I've never used that number_format but when a echo this the number shows right for me like 3,123.03 .

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `3,123.03`

That's not a number literal, that's two numbers, `3` and `123.03`, one of which is apparently interpreted as column name. Remove the grouping `,` in the number literal expression or use `TO_NUMBER()` and a string literal with the formatted number representation.

The best way however would be not to build queries by string concatenation but parametrized queries. String concatenation is prone to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Also parametrized queries find the right representation for the DBMS (usually and mostly) automatically, avoiding such problems you have here.

Comment: I tested it and it works, how did I not think of it? !!! Thank you very much for your help. About the String concatenaton on queries, that is not the case... I have two combos where the user select only the year and month, i use these on queries to bring me the values to use it on my main query. But is a good advice thank you.